# Can I edit and add code after Unity3d project is ported to IOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, porting

My question is whether I can add new code to the code I get after porting the Unity project to IOS. For example add a login page before the actual unity project scene starts. Is it possible to do this? Or can I do the same in Unity and then port it to IOS?

Comment: I believe it is better to do it with Unity. There are 3 advantages for this: 1-It will be cross-platform (if you need it, of course). 2-The code of the iOS with Unity is quite complex. I wouldn't try to modify it, because it will probably break it. 3-Whenever you update the Unity part, you need to re-implement the login on the iOS part. If you do the login with Unity, this will not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @ant0nisk on points 1 and 2. Another way would be to write a plugin for iOS and integrate it in the xCode project. As an example - make the first scene blank in Unity with a single game object to call the LoginViewController on the xCode side. This gameObject also would wait until there is a response from xCode (success/failure). Basically you can have a whole new iOS app built in xCode running while the Unity's blank scene is waiting.

I disagree with ant0nisk 's 3rd point: once you have your xCode project set up and need to change something in Unity do this: make change in Unity and make a so called "trash build" in some other directory (not in your original xCode project). Then copy the "Data" and "Library" folders from the trash build and replace in the original xCode project. If you are building an ill2cpp project you will also need to replace "Classes/Native" folder. [Here is the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-BuildProcess.html) but it's a bit old and they don't say anything about ill2cpp builds. I had to figure it out by myself but it works.

p.s. read about [writing iOS unity plugins here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply. The link for the documentation seems to be broken.

Comment: my bad, fixed it up :)